# Table view scrolling issue inside a tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uitabbarcontroller

I am using a tabbarcontroller and I have embedded childcontoller of tabbarcontroller inside navigation controller .I am using a scrollview inside the childcontroller and to the bottom is my tableview.On Scrolling to the bottom the tableview having 5 elements in array shows only 2 elements.[image]

I have tried this code to manage height of tableview inside scrollview

- (void)viewDidLoad

{

[super viewDidLoad];

int height =_PreviousComplaintArray.count*77;

```
_tableView.frame=CGRectMake(_tableView.frame.origin.x, _tableView.frame.origin.y,
```

_tableView.frame.size.width,height);

[_tableView reloadData];

}

-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews

{

[self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];

self.tblhght.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height+50;

NSLog(@"size is %d",self.tblhght.constant);

}

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using auto-layout?

Comment: offcourse I have used auto layouts

Comment: Then your problem might be mixing explicit `.frame` settings conflicting with auto-layout constraints. It's a little unclear... are you trying to use a non-scrolling table view embedded in a scroll view?